# Ubuntu NFS хранить папку home на сервере

Tags: nfs, ubuntu

История следующая: сделал я бездисковую систему, которая по iscsi загружается. Но сам диск iscsi сделал маленьким 16GB, в установке ubuntu проблемы были, но, в общем-то, я их все порешал. Далее встал вопрос следующий. Установил я на сервере nfs-kernel-server и расшарил папочку в файле /etc/exports вот таким образом:

```
/srv/nfs/home                   *(rw,no_subtree_check)
```

Перезагрузил nfs сервер и получил

```
#exportfs -v
/srv/nfs/home   <world>(rw,wdelay,root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

т.е. как бы папку я создал и расшарил. А что делать на машине клиенте, чтобы эта папка совместилась с /home, я не понимаю. Точнее понимаю, что мне надо ее прописать в fstabs, но как именно, чтобы она правильно работала?

Сервер имеет ip 192.168.1.10 хост 192.168.1.11, подскажите, пожалуйста, правильные действия. По сути, там у меня один пользователь, возможно, даже стоит просто сделать "шару" для него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SERV_IP:/srv/nfs/home/ /home nfs rw,rsize=4096,wsize=4096,hard,intr,async,nodev,nosuid 0 0

Comment: Собственно, вопрос неактуальный, ответ приблизительно такой и получился. Спасибо за ваши труды. Только я еще время обновления выставлял.

Answer (score 1):

[Монтировать](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-nfs-fstab.html).

Еще можно `man 8 mount` почитать.

--

Вот пример /etc/fstab

```
manager01:/soft /mnt/soft   nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
storage:/soft /mnt/hpcsoft nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
#10.2.240.29:/soft /hpcsoft nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```